# Incorrect Y value when calculating coordinates for PDF annotation using react-pdf and pdf-lib

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf, pdf-lib.js

I'm using react-pdf to render a PDF document in my react app. I've added a function to get the coordinates of the user's click. But when I calculate the Y value based on the `clientY` and containerRect, and pass these calculated coordinates to pdf-lib to insert a text field, the field appears way above the clicked position. The Y coordinate seems to be incorrect.

Any suggestions why this would be happening?

React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/TextLayer.css';
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;

export default function PDFViewer() {
  const handleClick = async (event) => {
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;
    const page = document.querySelector('[data-page-number="6"]');
    const containerRect = page.getBoundingClientRect();

    const x = clientX - containerRect.left;
    const y = clientY - containerRect.top;

    console.log('Clicked at coordinates:', x, y);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Document file='ps-test.pdf'>
        <Page pageNumber={6} onClick={handleClick} />
      </Document>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Node code:

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
const page = pdfDoc.getPage(5);
const textFieldStyles = {
  width: 260,
  height: 14,
  borderWidth: 1,
  backgroundColor: rgb(1, 1, 1),
};

const dateField = form.createTextField('candidates.date');
dateField.setText('');
dateField.addToPage(page, {
  ...textFieldStyles,
  x: 106,
  y: 478,
});

const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

fs.writeFileSync('my-pdf.pdf', pdfBytes);
```